# Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager re-using object in different requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I've set up Unity for dependency injection for our project. The project itself is an ASP.NET application that uses both MVC and Web API.

For the database context, I'm using the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. This is done so that the different bits of business logic are using the same context (and thus the same transaction).

In order to be able to use the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`, I've added references to the nuget packages *Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC* and *Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API*.

For use of this lifetime manager in Web API, the following line has been added to the startup code:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

The Unity container is set up for both MVC and Web API:

```
var container = BuildUnityContainer();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

In building the Unity container, the database context is set up to be resolved per request in the following way:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        // Some code
        return new DataContext(/* params */);
    }
));
```

However, it seems that this code is not giving me a new `DataContext` for each request. It is giving me the same context in different places within a single request (which is fine). However, subsequent (web api) requests are being given the same instance of `DataContext` where I would expect a new one to be created for each new request. I also would expect the `DataContext` to be properly disposed of after the request is finished (the class implements `IDisposable`).

What's going on here? Am I missing a bit of configuration to make this work properly? Or isn't this supposed to work the way I expect it to?

Comment: It probably caches the InjectionFactory call. Can you try without it? I imagine the problem will be that you want to have different parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the `UnityDependencyResolver` was caching the resolved items over several requests. I had to change it to the `UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver` and then it started resolving my items properly according to the associated `LifetimeManager`. The problem initially became more confusing when it appeared that even when using a `TransientLifetimeManager`, it would still return the same instance.

I found the answer in a different (yet somewhat related) question: [using a Handler in Web API and having Unity resolve per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483574/using-a-handler-in-web-api-and-having-unity-resolve-per-request)

So all I did was change

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

to

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
```

and all my problems were solved.

Comment: Any root cause of the reason ?