# Unity Container PerRequestLifetimeManager in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I have a WEB API application and I am using UnityContainer as my DI. 
Since I'm using UnitOfWork with Entity Framework I wanted to register the DataContext in the UnityContainer per each request.
I was disappointed to find that no LifeTimeManager exists that can give me a new scope per request. After digging a little more, I found that Unity.AspNet.Mvc does contain a PerRequestLifetimeManager. My questions are:

1. Is there a reason why Unity doesn't contain a PerRequestLifetimeManager? It seems to me that is a very common case to register something per request.
2. Is there a particular reason why Unity.AspNet.Mvc does contain PerRequestLifetimeManager?
3. Is there something I need to know if I am using Unity.AspNet.Mvc in a WebApi project?
4. In case of using Thread or Tasks, how does the container knows it belongs to the same request?

Comment: What about a `UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065538/unity-perrequestlifetimemanager-re-using-object-in-different-requests)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work @PeterBons

Comment: It didn't work, because...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a reason why Unity doesn't contain a PerRequestLifetimeManager? It seems to me that is a very common case
>      to register something per request.

The core library is for .Net projects. Only Asp.Net would have a `Request`.

> Is there a particular reason why Unity.AspNet.Mvc does contain
>   PerRequestLifetimeManager?

Same as answer 1. Requests are an Asp.Net concept.

> Is there something I need to know if I am using Unity.AspNet.Mvc in a
>   WebApi project?

Nope. You will most likely only be using the PerRequestLifetimeManager anyway. I would imagine the developers of Unity didn't see a need to publish a Mvc and a WebApi package when the two libraries would have been identical.

> In case of using Thread or Tasks, how does the container knows it
>   belongs to the same request?

The container is just another object. The .Net framework manages objects from request to request and thread to thread. The container itself creates a unique scope at the beginning of a request and destroys it at the end of the request .Net does everything in between.

Comment: To clarify this answer, you can reference `Unity.AspNet.Mvc` from a WebApi project, and the PerRequestLifetimeManager works fine for API requests.  You still use Unity.AspNet.WebApi for the web activator to hook into the pipeline.